# Нормально ли что ruby выдает warning при запуске

Tags: linux, ruby

Всем привет!
Я с **ruby** столкнулся впервые за всю свою практику
До меня кем то написан скрипт который парсит лог файлы и результат пишет в **mysql** базу
Скрипт перестал работать
Пофиксил обновлением ruby и обновлением библиотеки на которую он ругался
Скрипт запускается
Но вот при запуске в verbose вижу такое

```
usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:29: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:30: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/eglobal/bin/sla_mt4/lastday_parser_to_mysql_mt4_log.rb:55: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'if' at 38
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
```

Может ли это быть причиной что он не пишет значения в бд или может вообще ничего не парсит?
Далее выводит в консоль в принципе нужные результаты
но в бд ничего нет
Ошибок связанных с бд тоже нет

Не могу понять как его троблшутить

Ранее все работало

Debian 9

Comment: Конкретно эти варнинги не должны влиять на его работу. Мне кажется, вам есть смысл рассказать подробнее про "Скрипт перестал работать" и как вы это пофиксили - может быть именно там всё пошло не так